# Can I test a SharePoint solution on a remote server?

Tags: sandbox-solution, solution-deployment

I want to develop a SharePoint Solution event receiver (not SharePoint app) on a computer with visual studio 2013 but without SharePoint. SharePoint will run on a different computer on the same LAN.

As far as I know that I can do that to develop SharePoint apps but I get

> “the required version of SharePoint is not installed on this system”

errors when trying to do the same for SharePoint solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop app for SharePoint solutions in Visual Studio 2013 if Microsoft SharePoint 2013 is installed on a remote server. However, you must install Microsoft SharePoint 2013 locally before you can develop other SharePoint solutions.

So in your case if you are not targeting an app then its not possible to develop SharePoint solutions.

To remotely develop app for SharePoint solutions, you must install the following components.

1. A server operating system and a version of SharePoint 2013 on one server.
2. Developers must have Full Control permissions on the subsite of the server that's running SharePoint. For example, if a developer is creating an app for SharePoint on http://myserver/devweb, the developer must have Full Control permissions for devweb. The developer doesn't need site collection administrator permissions.
3. Each developer’s system must also have the following components installed on it.

   - Windows 7 or later version
   - Visual Studio 2012 or later version
   - Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio
   - You install the Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio by using the Microsoft Web Platform, which installs all of the required components.

Source - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220047(v=office.15).aspx#RDOverview